# how to pass object array to another function ONLY when all getjson calls completed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, getjson

i have to make a few getjson calls to get some data from google spreadsheet and store the data i need to an array and filter the array and display the data. My current code some time for large amount of data passes array before my first getjson finishes so i end up with incomplete data in my array!

Is there a way that my last getjson sends the array to another function only when all previous getjson calls finished (including itself) before passing the array to another function?

```
    <script>
        var files = new Array();

           function pushtoArray(){

        //first getjson call
        var url1 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxx/xxxxx/public/values?alt=json"; 
            $.getJSON(url1, function(data) {

              var entry = data.feed.entry;

              $(entry).each(function(){
                // Column names are name, age, etc.
            count++;
             files.push({ url: this.gsx$url.$t, filename: this.gsx$name.$t });



              });

            alert(files.length);
            print_r(files);
            console.log(files);
            });//end of ajax call

        //second getjson call
    var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxx/xxxxx/public/values?alt=json"; 
            $.getJSON(url2, function(data) {

              var entry = data.feed.entry;

              $(entry).each(function(){
                // Column names are name, age, etc.
            count++;
             files.push({ url: this.gsx$url.$t, filename: this.gsx$name.$t });


              });

            alert(files.length);
           passArray(files);
            console.log(files);
            });//end of ajax call


            };//end of function


    function passArray(files){ 
    alert(files.length);
    console.log(files);

   // do some data filtering from array passed

        </javascript>
    <body onload="pushtoArray()">
```

**edit:** i changed

```
var entry1 = resultFromUrl1.feed.entry;
        var entry2 = resultFromUrl2.feed.entry;
```

to

```
 var entry1 = resultFromUrl1[0].feed.entry;
    var entry2 = resultFromUrl2[0].feed.entry;
```

and it fixed the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Promises.

```
var promiseA = $.getJSON(urla..);
var promiseB = $.getJSON(urlb..);

$.when(promiseA, promiseB).then(function(resultA,resultB){
//do whatever you want with results.

});
```

EDIT:Here's your code edited, maybe an issue with `var entry = ...` if so then just look at entry1 and entry2 in debug:

```
var files = new Array();

function pushtoArray() {

    //first getjson call
    var url1 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxx/xxxxx/public/values?alt=json";
    var url1Promise = $.getJSON(url1, function (data) {
        console.log("url1 success");
    });//end of ajax call

    //second getjson call
    var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxx/xxxxx/public/values?alt=json";
    var url2Promise = $.getJSON(url2, function (data) {
        console.log("url2 success");
    });//end of function

    $.when(url1Promise, url2Promise).then(function (resultFromUrl1, resultFromUrl2) {
        var entry1 = resultFromUrl1.feed.entry;
        var entry2 = resultFromUrl2.feed.entry;

        var entry = entry1.concat(entry2);

        $(entry).each(function () {
            // Column names are name, age, etc.
            count++;
            files.push({ url: this.gsx$url.$t, filename: this.gsx$name.$t });
                    alert(files.length);
                    print_r(files);
                    console.log(files);


        });


    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. in my case promisesA will hold what data ? does it holds all the urls and filenames ? i need to extract those values an add them to array ? how to collect those data in array using promies ?

Comment: instead of adding a function to your getJSON call just save the call as a variable (promiseA for example). once you save that call promiseA will hold an object that has several functions, the most important one is "done" you can pass to done function a callback method that receives the JSON. however in my example because you want several JSON's to be returned you use $.when which waites for all of the promises to be completed and then you use `.then` to get all of the results to the same function.

Comment: i tried $("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(promiseA); inside when function but no data append ! i want to seee what is the content of promisesA before i go further ...

Comment: do this `promiseA.done(function(res){$("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(res)});`

Comment: btw if you just take the code I gave you above and where it says //do whatever you would append resultA and resultB to element you will see both results

Comment: i tried with one result i get nothing as output! does promiseA holds url and file name for me ? or the whole response of getjson ?

Comment: it gets the whole response of getJSON

Comment: well unfortunelty i can't confirm if i got the whole getjson ?f12 gives no error other then that getjson 200 status but how to khow i got the whole response if i can't append?  can i run  var entry = data.feed.entry;  $(entry).each(function(){ .... inside $.when to put the url and filename to array ?

Comment: i tried to run it i keep getting this error using f12: resultFromUrl1.feed is undefined
var entry1 = resultFromUr11.feed.entry;

Comment: if it reached that line then it returned ok from the JSON call.. just change it to what you want... use debug tools to see the value.. I gave you the best answer with the code you gave. if you don't want to use promise and you want to use a code convention that is not recommended just put the call of getJSON for url2 inside of the success function of url1